# iOS - solution for follow a user like Instagram

Tags: ios, notifications

I am working on a social network, users can follow other users.
I am having a bit of trouble when users press Follow button to follow another user.

Like Instagram, when you press any follow button in a view, all views will update the Follow status of you to that user (User list view, Profile View, Notification View,…). In real life scenario, it could be up to 5-10 views that need to be updated. How do we handle that situation? What I am doing is posting a notification and all views that listen to that notification will handle it differently, it works but it does not seem like an optimal solution.

Comment: You should handle this in your controller, not view.

Comment: Can you post some of your current code?